# Getting 'HostNameNotOnVerifiedDomain' when setting AppId uri on Azure AD application object

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I get an error 'Failed to update Application ID URI application property. Error detail: `Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain:'` when trying to set my appid uri property while trying to expose an api from my app registration.

Answer (score 4):

Guidance on the Azure AD docs states the identifier uri (aka AppId Uri) must use a default value provided which is `api://appIdGuid` or must use on of the allowed patterns which requires the host value to be a verified domain of the tenant. More information on AppId uri is available in the [application registration security best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-best-practices-for-app-registration#appid-uri-configuration) doc.
More information on the identifierUri attribute is available in the Azure AD [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-best-practices-for-app-registration#appid-uri-configuration) section.

Comment: This is a new thing from just a few days ago => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#appid-uri-in-single-tenant-applications-will-require-use-of-default-scheme-or-verified-domains

Comment: Update the az cli version if you are creating through cli.

Comment: Updating az cli doesn't fix the issue in all cases. I tried with  v2.32.0, but `az ad app create` still has the same error in this post. Found some more info here that provides a translation of the microsoft docs: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-new-restrictions-to-azurewebsitesnet-domain